# Linux max threads count

Tags: linux, multithreading

my server has been running with Amazon Ec2 linux. I have a mongodb server inside. The mongodb server has been running under heavily load, and, unhappily , I've ran into a problem with it :/

As known, the mongodb creates new thread for every client connection, and this worked fine before. I don't know why, but MongoDB can't create more than 975 connections on the host as a non-privileged user ( it runs under a mongod user) . But when I'm running it as a root user, it can handle up to 20000 connections(mongodb internal limit). But, further investigations show, that problem isn't the MongoDB server, but a linux itself.

I've found a simple program, which checks max connections number:

```
/* compile with:   gcc -lpthread -o thread-limit thread-limit.c */
/* originally from: http://www.volano.com/linuxnotes.html */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 100000
#define PTHREAD_STACK_MIN 1*1024*1024*1024
int i;

void run(void) {
  sleep(60 * 60);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rc = 0;
  pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t thread_attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);

  printf("Creating threads ...\n");
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS && rc == 0; i++) {
    rc = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), &thread_attr, (void *) &run, NULL);
    if (rc == 0) {
      pthread_detach(thread[i]);
      if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0)
    printf("%i threads so far ...\n", i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Failed with return code %i creating thread %i (%s).\n",
         rc, i + 1, strerror(rc));

      // can we allocate memory?
      char *block = NULL;
      block = malloc(65545);
      if(block == NULL)
        printf("Malloc failed too :( \n");
      else
        printf("Malloc worked, hmmm\n");
    }
  }
sleep(60*60); // ctrl+c to exit; makes it easier to see mem use
  exit(0);
}
```

And the sutuation is repeated again, as root user I can create around 32k threads, as non-privileged user(mongod or ec2-user ) around 1000 .

This is an ulimit for root user:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59470
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 60000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

This is an ulimit for mongod user:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59470
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 60000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 1024
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Kernel max threads:

```
bash-4.1$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max 
118940
```

SELinux is disabled. Don't know how to solve this strange problem...Possibly, somebody does?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is the `max user processes` limit.

From the [`getrlimit(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) man page:

> `RLIMIT_NPROC`
>   The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads) that can be created for the real user ID of the calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, `fork(2)` fails with the error `EAGAIN`.

Same for [`pthread_create(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> `EAGAIN` Insufficient resources to create another thread, or a system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.  The latter case may  occur in two ways: the `RLIMIT_NPROC` soft resource limit (set via `setrlimit(2)`), which limits the number of process for a real user ID, was reached; or the kernel's system-wide limit on the number of threads, `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, was reached.

Increase that limit for your user, and it should be able to create more threads, until it reaches other resource limits.
Or plain resource exhaustion - for 1Mb stack and 20k threads, you'll need a lot of RAM.
See also [NPTL caps maximum threads at 65528?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521485/nptl-caps-maximum-threads-at-65528): `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` could become an issue at some point.

Side point: you should use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`. See [gcc - significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling).

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue when connection issues from the mongo client (java) get interrupted (it seems by the AWS network). With TCP_KEEPALIVE set to 7200 (2 hours), the connections in connection pools build up within this 2 hour window, and mongod dies when it hits 975 connections.

The mongo production checklist suggests keepalives of a much lower time (5 minutes); setting that should help you avoid the connection limit as well.